# JSF remove invalid component from page

Tags: jsf, invalidation, icefaces-1.8

i'm using JSF 1.2 with IceFaces 1.8.

On my page i got an selectOneListbox, which content (e.g. EQUAL TO, BETWEEN, IN) triggers inputText fields to be rendered. If EQUAL TO is choosen one field is rendered else if BETWEEN is chossen two fields are rendered.

If my validation on the inputText field fails, and i change the content of the listbox the explained rendering does not work.

So has anyone a suggestion how to remove an "invalid" component from the html page?

Answer (score 0):

I set invalid components to invisible.

I use the `visible="#{myManagedBean.fieldVisible}"` attribute for the component
in my JSF page
and 
`public boolean isFieldVisible() { return flag; }`
in my Managed Bean to achieve this.